# Setting WSL to CWD in VSCode Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have ubuntu installed on my windows 10 machine and have been using vscode.  I'd like to use the wsl integrated terminal.  If I just open vscode and then a new wsl terminal it shows my path as:
`username@Computer:/mnt/c/Users/winusername`

If I then open a project folder (not workspace), and then a new terminal it shows as:
`username@Computer:~`

This isn't in my project folder location- is there a way to get the wsl integrated terminal to set the project location as the current working directory?

Git bash does this just fine if I use it as my terminal, like this:

`winusername@Computer MINGW64 /d/my/project/path`

But I'd like to use wsl.

Comment: Where is your project folder; in wsl or in Windows? Where is vscode installed in wsl or in Windows? Did you add any tasks.json or settings.json? Which project C/C++?

Comment: @Biswapriyo project folder is in windows, as is the vscode installation.  Didn't add any tasks.json or settings.json.  Project type is python and simple editing (markup, AWS CFN templates, docker files, etc.)

Comment: I think its duplicate version and briefly explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305050/changing-the-default-path-of-visual-studio-codes-integrated-terminal

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly the same issue, but similar symptom due to a different cause.

When I'd open a project folder (not workspace) and land on my `username@Computer:~` rather than the project dir that I just opened.

It was due to my pretty "clever" solution of placing a `cd ~` in my `.bashrc|.zshrc` intending to replace the WSL default behavior of launching your terminal at the `/mnt/...` path instead of the WSL distro user dir (`/home/username`).

In other words:

WSl default behavior when you launch a new WSL distro terminal window is to start at the:

```
➜  windowsusername pwd
/mnt/...
```

I tried to "fix" that by adding the following to my `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
cd ~
```

That made my terminals to always open at my distro home dir which's convenient for me, but also messed up my vscode terminal since it was naturally always changing the directory to my distro home user dir `/home/distrousername` too before any other task.

```
➜  ~ pwd
/home/distrousername
```

A few extra side effects of that unthoughtful approach were my vscode debugger not able to attach to my nodejs server and my `jest` vscode extension not able to trigger the tests via extension utilities (e.g.. the `Debug` buttons that the extension adds to your `*.test.js|ts` or `*.spec.js|ts`).

Not a straight answer to the problem reported above, but might help someone dropping here for the same reasons that I did.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for this one! My case was similar: had a `cd ~` in my .bashrc because of an old Windows Terminal bug (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6995).

Comment: I have spent so much time trying to figure it out. Of course it was something dumb like this 

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @AlanBueno
This worked for me :-)

```sh
if [ "$NAME" != "Code" ]; then
    cd ~
else
    cd $OLDPWD
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both @AlanBueno and @Dexter Le Blanc Jr.

I think the following has proved to be more stable for me across multiple IDEs.

```sh
if [ "$NAME" != "Code" ]; then
    cd ~
fi
```

Comment: For me $NAME was always blank, I fixed this by going into user settings and clicking **Edit in settings.json** for the `terminal.integrated.env.linux` setting. I then manually added an entry that sets NAME = "Code" which fixed all my issues

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration is little screwed.

Check the terminal configuration about User settings and workspace settings.

You can find in an easy way on UI.

1. File > Preference > Settings
2. Check the default 'integrated terminal' path, and `cwd` value.

   > in my case using `wsl.exe` for default terminal, not `bash.exe`

[image]
[image]

3. compare with `User settings` and `Workspace settings` on the upside on UI about same options keys.(You can compare in easy just tapping the title)
4. if nothing trouble on your settings, i recommend this VSCODE extension.
   It helps open terminal with path with opened file. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here&ssr=false

Answer (score 0):

I edited my `settings.json` like this and it did work:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "${fullPathToExecutable}",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["run"],
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\Users\\winusername"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked the best:

```
CALLER="$PWD"
APP="${CALLER##*/}"

if [ "$APP" != "Microsoft VS Code" ]; then
    cd ~
else
   cd $OLDPWD
fi
```

My VSCode got that name...