# How do I change path of the 'Run File In Dedicated Terminal' arrow button in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I changed the path of my default terminal so that the YELLOW CIRCLE opens the terminal in my selected path.

However when I run the script from the RED CIRCLE it does not use the default path I set (from this guide [Changing the default path of Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305050/changing-the-default-path-of-visual-studio-codes-integrated-terminal))

How do I set the terminal path for this 'Run File' arrow button?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVNjK.png]